# Building wsp from post-build event command line

Tags: sharepoint, wsp

What is the command for building WSP from post-build event command line?

[image]

I'm adding one more image so that you can understand my exact requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0462dad3-1d56-4333-85a5-eafd1dd40980) and it works for both SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

**call** "C:\Program Files\WSPTools\WSPBuilderExtensions\WSPBuilder.exe" -ProjectPath $(SolutionDir) -OutputPath $(SolutionDir) -SolutionPath $(SolutionDir)

Answer (score 3):

You can build a WSP by using MSBuild. Each SharePoint project is build with the parameter

```
IsPackaging=True
```

By adding this parameter to the msbuild command you can ensure that all WSPs will be created.

Comment: Nice and useful info buddy. Previously in our build we are using wspbuilder and executing it through exec task. Now it is made easy. Thousand fold thanks for you

Comment: More details: http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2011/04/sharepoint-2010-wsp-packaging-on-vs2010.html  (adding <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);CreatePackage</BuildDependsOn> to the project file)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to depend on external tools like makecab.exe or WSPBuilder.

http://www.developerfusion.com/community/blog-entry/8390127/tfs-teambuild-and-sharepoint-wsp-deployment-and-any-post-build-events-for-that-matter/

http://www.fftf.org/news/Jul07feed/SharePoint_Solution_Deployment_Handy_PostBuild_Events.rss.html

Comment: I don't want to create "Build Deployment package". I just want to create WSP from command line. I'm finding the command to build WSP on post-build event command line of my project.

Comment: I have added one more image for your reference.

Comment: +1 Yes its possible using makecab.exe also. But I was finding commands specific to WSPBuilder only. Thanks. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be VS2010.
If you choose the project template to be a SharePoint 2010 project then you will find items in the context menu that are related to SharePoint. If you choose deploy, it will create the wsp package automatically and deploy it to the server.

Comment: :) Dear but I don't want to deploy while building WSP. My requirement is very specific. My requirement is just building WSP from command line. I have a separate installer for installation.

Answer (score 0):

To force Visual Studio to create a wsp on post build for SharePoint solutions, add these properties to the project xml.  If you already have a post build event defined, just add the two inner tags to the existing property group. Visual Studio will create the wsp in the configured location; Release or Debug.

To edit the project xml unload the project in visual studio then right-click on the project and select edit.

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <IsDebugging>False</IsDebugging>
 <PostBuildEventDependsOn>$(PostBuildEventDependsOn);CreatePackage</PostBuildEventDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```